# Least value of slope of tangent to hyperbola

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry

While studying hyperbola, I came across a question:

> Let $y=mx+c$ is a tangent to a hyperbola $$\cfrac{x^2}{ \lambda^2} -\cfrac{y^2}{( \lambda^3+ \lambda^2+\lambda)^2} = 1$$Find least value of $16m^2$.

My attempt:

As $y =mx +c$  is tangent so $c^2=a^2m^2-b^2$ then I put value of $a$ and $b$ and I take  derivative of it but there is no information about $\lambda$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried with a given hyperbola and some points?

Comment: Where does $c^2=a^2m^2-b^2$ come from? What do $a$ and $b$ stand for?

Comment: a=lamda ,b=lambda^3+lamda^2+lamda

Comment: Least value of 16m^2 given in answer is 9

Comment: If you are looking for the least slope, then you can find the slope right under the right vertex; it will have a slope of $-\infty$. Are you instead looking for the least absolute value of the slope?

Comment: Least real number for m because i need to find value of  16m^2

Comment: Sir i really want how to approach this question

Comment: There only four option in answer 0,1,4,or 9 can you please show your method that how you got this

Comment: Have you deleted your answer

Comment: @yuvrajsingh Do you got my answer?

Answer (score 2):

As you have said $c^2  = a^2 m^2 - b^2$ ,On placing values$$  c = \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2 m^2 - (\lambda + \lambda^2 + \lambda^3)^2}$$
$$ \implies {\lambda^2 m^2 - (\lambda + \lambda^2 + \lambda^3)^2} \ge 0 $$
$$ \implies \lambda^2( m^2 - (1 + \lambda + \lambda^2)^2 )\ge 0 $$
Assuming $ \lambda \ne 0$, $$ m^2 \ge ( 1 + \lambda + \lambda^2)^2 $$
As nothing is specified about the nature of values of $ \lambda$, it can be assumed that $\lambda \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$. Least value of the polynomial $ 1 + \lambda + \lambda^2$ is $\dfrac{3}{4}$
$$ \implies m^2 \ge \dfrac{9}{16} \implies 16 m^2 \ge 9 $$

Comment: Sir last step how you take least is value is 3/4 for lambda quadratic equation

Comment: Let $f( x) = 1 + x + x^2$, on differentiating and equating the derivative to zero(for finding minima, as there is not maxima), $f'(x) = 2x + 1 = 0 \implies x = - 0.5$ , place this in the $f(x)$, you will get the minima